# delete all the duplicate element with array_unique PHP

Tags: php

I have this following array :

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-07
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 3060
            [4] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-07
            [1] => 270
            [2] => 757
            [3] => 13812810
            [4] => 4
        )
```

And i want to delete all the duplicated elements and replace `$month[1][4]` with it sum:

```
  $result = array_reduce($month, function($cur, $x)
{ 
return $cur + $x[4];
 }, 0);
$month = array_unique($month); //<---- Exception
$month[1][4]=$result;
```

It works fine but it displays me this exception `Notice: Array to string conversion` ! 
How can I prevent this from happening?

Thanks

Comment: what line is the exception for?

Comment: Edited my post! Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick Answer**: use:

```
$unique = array_unique($a, SORT_REGULAR);
    // OR    
$unique = array_map('unserialize', array_unique(array_map('serialize', $a)));
```

**Explanation**
The problem comes about because you're using a multi-dimensional array, [array_unique()](http://php.net/array_unique) uses using string conversion before comparing the values to find the unique values:

> **Note**: Two elements are considered equal if and only if `(string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2`. In words: when the string representation is the same. The first element will be used.

An array will always convert to "Array" when casting it to a string:

```
var_dump("Array" === (string) array());
```

You can solve this by specifying the `SORT_REGULAR` mode in the second parameter of `array_unique`:

```
$unique = array_unique($a, SORT_REGULAR);
```

Or, if that doesn’t work, by [serializing](http://php.net/serialize) the arrays before and [unserializing](http://php.net/unserialize) it after calling `array_unique` to find the unique values:

```
$unique = array_map('unserialize', array_unique(array_map('serialize', $a)));
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what you need:

```
$month= array_unique($month, SORT_REGULAR);
```

Comment: $month= array_unique($month, SORT_REGULAR); this what you need